# IIS and root application

Tags: iis-7, root

Sorry for my bad english :)
I am new to Windows Server and is about to set up a website.

I go to the IIS and added a new website. 
Then I add a application to that website. 
Lets say the application is called MyApp, then the URL is mydomain.com/MyApp/

What do I have to do to just make it mydomain.com and not show the MyApp?

So im looking for a way to make it the root.

Comment: Why can't you just set it up as as the root of the website, rather than as an application?  Point the website at the /MyApp/ folder, and be done with it?

Comment: Because i read some place that every website should have a application? And if i can do that, then whats the differens between a application and i website?

Comment: Nothing...A website is an application.  What've you've created is a sub-application, which can serve a purpose, but not in your case, where you don't have anything else to run at the root.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it doesn't look like you have a particular reason to run this application below the root, and you don't have anything else running at the root of the website, so the correct solution would be to point the root of the website at the /MyApp/ folder, and call it job done.